# How to convert annotations in 'odgt' (JSON?) format to 'csv' format

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

I am building person recognition algorithm with TensorFlow and would like to train my own algorithm with [CrowdHuman](http://www.crowdhuman.org/) dataset and they have already pre-made annotations but in `odgt` format (they say it is JSON, but when I change extension it does not work).

My question is : how to use those annotations to train TensorFlow algorithm or how to convert them to `csv` format.

Each line of file looks like:

```
   {
      "ID": "284193,faa9000f2678b5e",
      "gtboxes": [
         {
            "tag": "person",
            "hbox": [
               123,
               129,
               63,
               64
            ],
            "head_attr": {
               "ignore": 0,
               "occ": 1,
               "unsure": 0
            },
            "fbox": [
               61,
               123,
               191,
               453
            ],
            "vbox": [
               62,
               126,
               154,
               446
            ],
            "extra": {
               "box_id": 0,
               "occ": 1
            }
         },
         {
            "tag": "person",
            "hbox": [
               214,
               97,
               58,
               74
            ],
            "head_attr": {
               "ignore": 0,
               "occ": 1,
               "unsure": 0
            },
            "fbox": [
               165,
               95,
               187,
               494
            ],
            "vbox": [
               175,
               95,
               140,
               487
            ],
            "extra": {
               "box_id": 1,
               "occ": 1
            }
         },
         {
            "tag": "person",
            "hbox": [
               318,
               109,
               58,
               68
            ],
            "head_attr": {
               "ignore": 0,
               "occ": 1,
               "unsure": 0
            },
            "fbox": [
               236,
               104,
               195,
               493
            ],
            "vbox": [
               260,
               106,
               170,
               487
            ],
            "extra": {
               "box_id": 2,
               "occ": 1
            }
         },
         {
            "tag": "person",
            "hbox": [
               486,
               119,
               61,
               74
            ],
            "head_attr": {
               "ignore": 0,
               "occ": 0,
               "unsure": 0
            },
            "fbox": [
               452,
               110,
               169,
               508
            ],
            "vbox": [
               455,
               113,
               141,
               501
            ],
            "extra": {
               "box_id": 3,
               "occ": 1
            }
         },
         {
            "tag": "person",
            "hbox": [
               559,
               105,
               53,
               57
            ],
            "head_attr": {
               "ignore": 0,
               "occ": 0,
               "unsure": 0
            },
            "fbox": [
               520,
               95,
               163,
               381
            ],
            "vbox": [
               553,
               98,
               70,
               118
            ],
            "extra": {
               "box_id": 4,
               "occ": 1
            }
         },
         {
            "tag": "person",
            "hbox": [
               596,
               40,
               72,
               83
            ],
            "head_attr": {
               "ignore": 0,
               "occ": 0,
               "unsure": 0
            },
            "fbox": [
               546,
               39,
               202,
               594
            ],
            "vbox": [
               556,
               39,
               171,
               588
            ],
            "extra": {
               "box_id": 5,
               "occ": 1
            }
         },
         {
            "tag": "person",
            "hbox": [
               731,
               139,
               69,
               83
            ],
            "head_attr": {
               "ignore": 0,
               "occ": 0,
               "unsure": 0
            },
            "fbox": [
               661,
               132,
               183,
               510
            ],
            "vbox": [
               661,
               132,
               183,
               510
            ],
            "extra": {
               "box_id": 6,
               "occ": 0
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: what are you expecting the csv output to look like?

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: also can you provide the first two lines of the file, not just 1 line as in your post above?

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly unclear as to how you want your output to look, but going off of what you provided, I'd imagine you could iterate through the items in the json, and use `json_normalize` to flatten it out, and then append that into a final dataframe to write to disk. So something like:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize           
import json
import pandas as pd     

df = pd.DataFrame()
for each in data:

    temp_df = json_normalize(each['gtboxes'])
    temp_df ['ID'] = each['ID']

    df = df.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv('path/filename.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
   extra.box_id  extra.occ                  fbox                hbox  head_attr.ignore  head_attr.occ  head_attr.unsure     tag                  vbox                      ID
0             0          1   [61, 123, 191, 453]  [123, 129, 63, 64]                 0              1                 0  person   [62, 126, 154, 446]  284193,faa9000f2678b5e
1             1          1   [165, 95, 187, 494]   [214, 97, 58, 74]                 0              1                 0  person   [175, 95, 140, 487]  284193,faa9000f2678b5e
2             2          1  [236, 104, 195, 493]  [318, 109, 58, 68]                 0              1                 0  person  [260, 106, 170, 487]  284193,faa9000f2678b5e
3             3          1  [452, 110, 169, 508]  [486, 119, 61, 74]                 0              0                 0  person  [455, 113, 141, 501]  284193,faa9000f2678b5e
4             4          1   [520, 95, 163, 381]  [559, 105, 53, 57]                 0              0                 0  person    [553, 98, 70, 118]  284193,faa9000f2678b5e
5             5          1   [546, 39, 202, 594]   [596, 40, 72, 83]                 0              0                 0  person   [556, 39, 171, 588]  284193,faa9000f2678b5e
6             6          0  [661, 132, 183, 510]  [731, 139, 69, 83]                 0              0                 0  person  [661, 132, 183, 510]  284193,faa9000f2678b5e
```